# GraphQLError: There can be only one fragment named

Tags: graphql, graphql-js

On a client app built with [graphql-react](https://github.com/jaydenseric/graphql-react),

graphQL query strings are made of multiple fragments like so:

```js
const fragmentAddress = `
    fragment address on Address {
        id
        number
        street
        code
        city
    }
`

const fragmentOffice = `
    fragment office on Office {
        id
        address {
            ...address
        }
    }

    ${fragmentAddress}
`

const User = `
    query User($id: ID) {
        address {
            ...address
        }
        office {
            ...office
        }
    }

    ${fragmentAddress}
    ${fragmentOffice}
`
```

A query on `User` returns this error: `GraphQLError: There can be only one fragment named address`.

I saw that [graphql-tag](https://github.com/apollographql/graphql-tag/pull/214) has a dedup fonction, but it can't give a string back.

How is it possible to deduplicate fragments from a graphql query string?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I just [found the answer](https://github.com/apollographql/graphql-tag/issues/144#issuecomment-360861636):

use `graphql-tag` for dedpulication and `graphql/language/printer` to convert back to a string:

```js
import gql from 'graphql-tag'
import { print } from 'graphql/language/printer'

const fragmentAddress = gql`
    fragment address on Address {
        id
        number
        street
        code
        city
    }
`

const fragmentOffice = gql`
    fragment office on Office {
        id
        address {
            ...address
        }
    }

    ${fragmentAddress}
`

const User = gql`
    query User($id: ID) {
        address {
            ...address
        }
        office {
            ...office
        }
    }

    ${fragmentAddress}
    ${fragmentOffice}
`

const queryString = print(query)
```